# How to solve ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError: when running tests with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-activestorage

I'm getting a file not found error using ActiveStorage when running rspec and I don't know what's wrong.
This is how it's setup.

**storage.yml**

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>
```

**config/environments/test.rb**

```
config.active_storage.service = :test
```

**Factory**

```
factory :user do
  membership_approval { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new("#{Register::Engine.root}/spec/fixtures/membership.pdf", 'application/pdf') }
end
```

**Mail example**

```
def mail_example(user:)
  filename = user.membership_approval.filename.to_s
  attachments[filename] = user.membership_approval.download

  mail(
    ...
  )
end
```

When I run rspec I get the following error message when it tries to download the file.

**Error message**

```
ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError:
# ------------------
# --- Caused by: ---
# Errno::ENOENT:
#   No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/myuser/Projects/my_project/tmp/storage/nd/5h/nd5hlet2n2xa673f8v11ljbnru72
```

It works fine otherwise but I just can't seem to get it to work with rspec. When I'm debugging in rspec it looks like the file is attached to the object but not stored physically anywhere. Any ideas?

Best regards.

**EDIT**

I have also tried this approach in the factory but no luck, I still get the same error.

```
after(:build) do |user|
  user.membership_approval.attach(
    io: File.open("#{Register::Engine.root}/spec/fixtures/membership.pdf"),
    filename: 'membership.pdf',
    content_type: 'application/pdf'
  )
end
```

Comment: Have you configured the `test` section properly in the `storage.yml` file to point to Disk instead of S3?

Comment: Yes I have followed this guide [Active Storage doc](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html).`storage.yml` is pointing to disk and I have also set `config.active_storage.service = :test`. For what it's worth I have also tried with S3 but then I'm getting key not found error. I'm going to update my question with this info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered this same problem and I eventually figured out that the attachment is not persisted to the disk/storage solution until `.save` is called on the record.

So, in your case, you could trigger this in your factory with:

```
after(:build) do |user|
  user.membership_approval.attach(
    io: File.open("#{Register::Engine.root}/spec/fixtures/membership.pdf"),
    filename: 'membership.pdf',
    content_type: 'application/pdf'
  )
  user.save
end
```